# Accessing svelte store with $ notation causing Reference Error

Tags: store, svelte

I have a `store.js` file whose content is :

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export  const generateds = writable(0);

console.log("generateds", $generateds)
```

Each time I try to access $generateds (inside or outside this file) I get this error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $generateds is not defined
    at stores.js:4
    at main.js:6
```

When I use a store in a new project, there is no problem. I can't find what's the problem in my current project.

Here is the list of the npm packages I'm using :

```
── @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons@5.14.0
├── @material/layout-grid@7.0.0
├── @mdi/js@5.9.55
├── @rollup/plugin-commonjs@17.1.0
├── @rollup/plugin-node-resolve@11.2.0
├── @smui/button@1.0.0
├── @smui/card@1.0.0
├── @smui/drawer@1.0.0
├── @smui/fab@1.0.0
├── @smui/icon-button@1.0.0
├── @smui/list@1.0.0
├── @smui/select@1.0.0
├── @smui/textfield@1.0.0
├── @smui/top-app-bar@1.0.0
├── @sveltejs/svelte-virtual-list@3.0.1
├── autoprefixer@9.8.6
├── dropzone@5.7.2
├── eslint-plugin-svelte3@2.7.3
├── eslint@7.9.0
├── firebase@7.24.0
├── firestore-export-import@0.10.0
├── mathlive@0.59.0
├── node-sass@4.14.1
├── postcss@8.2.6
├── query-string@6.13.2
├── rollup-plugin-analyzer@4.0.0
├── rollup-plugin-css-only@3.1.0
├── rollup-plugin-livereload@2.0.0
├── rollup-plugin-postcss@4.0.0
├── rollup-plugin-sass@1.2.2
├── rollup-plugin-svelte@7.1.0
├── rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2
├── rollup@2.39.0
├── sass@1.32.7
├── sirv-cli@1.0.11
├── svelte-fa@2.1.1
├── svelte-loading-spinners@0.1.1
├── svelte-materialify@0.3.5
├── svelte-preprocess@4.6.9
├── svelte-routing@1.5.0
├── svelte@3.32.3
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The $ syntax to reference a store value can only be used inside a Svelte component. From [the docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#4_Prefix_stores_with_$_to_access_their_values) (emphasis mine):

> Any time you have a reference to a store, you can access its value **inside a component** by prefixing it with the $ character. This causes Svelte to declare the prefixed variable, and set up a store subscription that will be unsubscribed when appropriate.

If you need to get the value inside a normal JS file, you can either [subscribe to it](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/writable-stores) or use Svelte's [get function](https://svelte.dev/docs#get) (which subscribes to the store to get the value and immediately unsubscribes).

```js
import { generateds }  from './store.js';
import { get } from 'svelte/store';

// method 1
const unsubscribe = generateds.subscribe((val) => { console.log(val); });
unsubscribe();

// method 2
console.log(get(generateds));
```

Comment: what about this then: You're not limited to using $count inside the markup, either — you can use it anywhere in the <script> as well, such as in event handlers or reactive declarations. https://svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions

Comment: <script>, event handlers, and reactive declarations are all still inside Svelte components (.svelte files). Inside a Svelte component you can use the $ syntax to auto-subscribe to the store; everywhere else (.js or .ts files) you need to manually subscribe.

Comment: ah I see, I think I missed the fact that the OP was not inside a svelte component when I responded

Comment: I am getting the same error but I want to set the value instead of get Is there any option or alternative to set writable store outside .svelte component  ?

Comment: Thx, important notice on the get function that it `subscribes to the store to get the value and immediately unsubscribes` which can break your code if you expect that it works like $subsribedVar.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$generateds` only in `.svelte` components.
If you'd like to get the value of the store outside of a svelte component you can use `generateds.subscribe()` or [`get(generateds)`](https://svelte.dev/docs#get).

So you'r example can look like:

```
import { writable, get } from 'svelte/store';
export  const generateds = writable(0);

console.log("generateds", get(generateds))
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I had imported

`import { writable } from "svelte/types/runtime/store";`

instead of

`import { writable } from 'svelte/store';`