# Access data stored in Svelte store when changing tabs in browser

Tags: svelte

I'm relatively new to Svelte, and playing with some code I've found on the net, to create a simple shopping cart.

**My problem:**
I am unable to consume data stored in a Svelte store, when changing tabs in a browser.

**In detail:**
When running my demo, I am able to successfully add items from my shop into an array called `cart`, which I can store in a Svelte store called `cartcontents`. I can adjust the items stored in `cart` by clicking on plus or minus in my UI - the changes are reflected back to my `cartcontents` store.

However, if I switch tabs from my shopping cart to another tab, and switch back, I get an empty cart and `NaN` showing for the total (a calculated value).

This is what I have in the script block for my component (called `Shop.svelte`):

```html
<script>
  export let location;

  import { Router, Link, Route } from "svelte-routing";
  import { writable, get } from "svelte/store";
  import { counter, cartcontents } from "../stores.js";  
  import productlisting from "../productlisting.js";

  let cart = [];

  cart = $cartcontents;

  console.log("CART", cart)   <!----- THIS SHOWS CORRECT DETAILS
 
  let totalcount = 0;

  let products = productlisting;
  
  const addToCart = (product) => {
    for(let item of cart) {
      if(item.id === product.id) {
        product.quantity += 1
        cart = cart;
        return;
      }
    }
    cart = [...cart, product];
    counter.update(n => n + 1);
    cartcontents.update(n => [cart]);
  }
  
  const minusItem = (product) => {
    for(let item of cart) {
      if(item.id === product.id) {
        product.quantity -= 1
        counter.update(n => n - 1);
        cartcontents.update(n => [...n, cart]);  
        cart = cart;
        return;
      }
    }
    cart = [...cart, product]
  }
  
  const plusItem = (product) => {
    for(let item of cart) {
      if(item.id === product.id) {
        product.quantity += 1  
        counter.update(n => n + 1); 
        cartcontents.update(n => [...n, cart]);            
        cart = cart;
        return;
      }
    }
    cart = [...cart, product]      
  }

  $: total = cart.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.price * item.quantity, 0);
</script>
```

Here is what I have for the HTML markup in my component:

```html
<div class="product-list">
  {#each products as product}
  <div>
    <div class="image" style="background-image: url({product.image})"></div>
    <a href="/product/{product.id}"><h4>{product.name}</h4></a>
    <p class="money">
      ${product.price}
      <button on:click={() => addToCart(product)}>Add to cart</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  {/each}
</div>

{#if $counter > 0} 
  <div>
    <div class="cart-list">
      <h2>Cart</h2>    
      {#each cart as item }   <!--- THIS IS WHERE I'M EXPECTING ITEMS TO APPEAR WHEN SWITCHING BACK - EVEN WITH ITEMS IN, IT THROWS AN ERROR -->
        {#if item.quantity > 0}
          <div class="cart-item">
            <img width="50" src={item.image} alt={item.name}/>
            <div>{item.quantity}
              <button on:click={() => minusItem(item)}>-</button>
              <button on:click={() => plusItem(item)}>+</button>
            </div>
            <p class="money">${item.price * item.quantity}</p>
          </div>
        {/if}
      {/each}
    </div>
    <div class="total">
      <h4>Total: $ {total}</h4>
      <button>Checkout and Pay</button>
    </div>
  </div>
{:else}
  <div id="cart">
    <h2>Cart</h2>
    <span>There are no products in your cart</span>
  </div>
{/if}
```

I've seen answers listed in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66320707/accessing-svelte-store-with-notation-causing-reference-error) on SO, and tried changing the code to use `cart = get($cartcontents);` or `cartcontents.subscribe();`, but get `store.subscribe is not a function` or `$cartcontents.subscribe` is not a function.

My aim is to get `cart` initialized either as an empty array, or with products from `cartcontents`, depending on whether `cartcontents` is empty or has an array of products in it.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - can anyone help please?

Comment: You don't show your cartcontents store code. In your Shop.svelte this line is not reactive: cart = $cartcontents; Meaning will not update the cart if the store changes (receives an update). To make it reactive use:  $: cart = $cartcontents; In your html you can also code: {#each $cartcontents as item}

Comment: Thanks for this - here's my cartcontents store code:

```import { writable } from "svelte/store";

let counter = writable(0);
let cartcontents = writable([])

export { counter, cartcontents }```

I've tried replacing the existing cart = $cartcontents line with the code you've suggested. I've also tried iterating through using $cartcontents, but unfortunately neither this nor the above change have helped; the plus / minus buttons don't fire. I'm going to try seeing if I can move my cart products into the store, to see if this will help - any other suggestions will be welcome!

Comment: Yes. You should update the store and not cart. cart is just a local copy of your store contents. If you update it. It will be overridden bij the $: cart = ... There is no need for the local copy "cart" in Shop.svelte. You can always use: $cartcontents. Example: $: console.log($cartcontents); And have a look at a custom store where you can combine a writable and methods to add, remove .. products.

Comment: That makes sense - I've spent a bit of time to refactor code so that the cart now comes from stores only, and not locally. It seems to work OK now - thanks for your help!